# ::before element doesn't show up without display:flex

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-element

With below Code

```css
.quote {
  display: flex;
  /*?? without this, ::before doesn't show up*/
}

.quote::before {
  content: "";
  min-width: 8px;
  background-color: #F7DF94;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  Hello World
</div>
```

I am not sure why the ::before element won't show up if I remove the `display: flex`.
Code snippet in [JSbin here](https://jsbin.com/hodamup/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: By default, flex items will all try to fit onto one line. float or display on flex children have no effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:before` element doesn't "show up" because the default display property acts like `display: inline;` and you cannot set the with or height of an inline element.

Definition of width on MDN :

> Applies to:   all elements but non-replaced **inline elements**, table rows,
> and row groups

[[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#formal_definition)] (*emphasis mine*)
And the same goes for height, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#formal_definition)

When you set `display: flex;` on the parent, the children act like flex items that can have a width / height.
The initial value of `align-items` for flex items is `normal` (behaves like stretch in this context [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#values)). This value makes the items take 100% height.

If you don't want to use `display: flex;` on the parent, you could change the default property of the pseudo element to `display: inline-block;` but you will need to specify a height otherwise it won't display either. Note that there will be a white-space between the pseudo element and the content.
Here is an example :

```css
.quote::before {
  display:inline-block;
  content: "";
  min-width: 8px;
  min-height: 8px;
  background-color: #F7DF94;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  Hello World
</div>
```